# How to filter JavaScript Object by values?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a normalized Object like this (for example):

```
const raw = {
  1: { foo: 1, bar: 1, flag: 0 },
  4: { foo: 4, bar: 4, flag: 1 },
  11: { foo: 11, bar: 11, flag: 0 },
  ...
}
```

I wanna delete values which have `flag: 1`.

```
{
  1: { foo: 1, bar: 1, flag: 0 },
  11: { foo: 11, bar: 11, flag: 0 },
  ...
}
```

How can I do this immutably?

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using an Array, Set, or Map for this?

Comment: @Taichi is it an Array of objects? as you have mentioned in your comment?

Comment: @Brad I have my data in this format, cuz I can get datum easily like `raw[1]` . Please see https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr

Comment: @amrendersingh no, it is Object. I wanna convert raw like in the question

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var obj = {
  1: { foo: 1, bar: 1, flag: 0 },
  2: { foo: 2, bar: 2, flag: 1 },
  3: { foo: 3, bar: 3, flag: 0 }
}
var newobj = Object.assign({}, Object.values(obj).filter(o => o.flag != 1));
console.log(newobj);
```

You can use `reduce()` to keep the keys:

```js
var obj = {
  1: { foo: 1, bar: 1, flag: 0 },
  2: { foo: 2, bar: 2, flag: 1 },
  3: { foo: 3, bar: 3, flag: 0 }
}
var newobj = Object.keys(obj).reduce((a,c) => {
  if(obj[c].flag != 1) 
   a[c] = obj[c]; return a;
},{});
console.log(newobj);
```

Comment: I think this deletes keys of `raw`, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2):

You can object filtering by lodashjs.
https://lodash.com/docs/#filter

```
_.filter(obj, o => !o.flag);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys()` and `.reduce()` methods:

```js
let data = {
  1: { foo: 1, bar: 1, flag: 0 },
  2: { foo: 2, bar: 2, flag: 1 },
  3: { foo: 3, bar: 3, flag: 0 }
};

let result = Object.keys(data).reduce((a, c) => {
  if(data[c].flag !== 1)
    a[c] = Object.assign({}, data[c]);
  
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```